# Problem with installing rails-3 plugins (Win7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, windows-7

I'm newbie at ruby, I spent couple hours trying to find the way to install the plugin... but without any success, so here I am, very frustrated... please help.

OS: W7
ruby: ruby 1.9.2
rails: 3.0.5
msysgit: 1.7.4 (i did not any changes, just installation)
(is there anything else I should of mentioned?)

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git/
C:\Ruby\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: Permission denied -- script/plugin (LoadError)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `script/plugin` command (and all other `script/<exec>` commands) is no longer used in Rails 3, instead you should do:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
```

Comment: Thank you! Its quite hard to find any solution on web for rails3 that could be applied.